# How to plot community membership from imported data into R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I have communities extracted from a network using Infomap algorithm (which is one of the community detection algorithms) on text file. Each community is represented as row in txt file, and its member is list of nodes in same row. Example suppose we have 15 nodes distributed in 4 communities as in community.txt:

```
   community      its members   
      1           1  2  15  4  6    
      2           1  3  2      
      3           9  13 7  8  9     
      4           5  10  11  14
```

I imported it in R as :

```
    library(igraph)  
    community_table <- read.table("~/Desktop/community.txt", header= FALSE, sep = "",fill = TRUE )
    View(community_table)

        V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
     1  1 12 15  4  6 NA
     2  2  1  3  2 NA NA
     3  3  9 13  7  8  9
     4  4  5 10 11 14 NA
```

Now, I would like to plot community membership from this data as scatter plot having x axis as "number of nodes per community" and y axis is "number of communities". I have made some search and found that in the topic on this link [plotting communities in iGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829387/plotting-communities-in-igraph) , It seems (contract.vertices) can does the job, but I don’t know how to use it in case the community data imported into R.

Thanks so much for any suggestion and help

Comment: `igraph` is going to help you plot graphs as graphs. This data just requires re-formatting and straight plotting via `points` or `geom_point` in `ggplot2`. What steps have you taken to try to plot this on your own? Generally speaking, SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I have written some code but it does not help, as example I used (as.data.frame) to convert data in table to data frame then used (as.igraph) to covert it to graph object but here it does not work. So i gave some try but from initial step seems to be an issue !

Comment: I'm not sure you completely grok the way SO works. It's not a code-writing service.

Comment: @hrbmmstr try to be positive, I'm not saying write code to me. We are here to exchange the knowledge NOT TO LOOK THROUGH THE BOTTLENECK.

Comment: you aren't even reading documentation, though.